# How to protect managed solution in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Hi

I have  created a managed solution of crm 2011. I want that when I give it to client then it will work only one year.

Is it possible?

Comment: Define "work only one year"

Comment: The solution wouldn't enforce that, you'd need to code in a date/time check of some description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this accomplished in different ways. It isn't available out of the box, but as glosrob says above, you can accomplish this with some custom plugins.

If you already have plugins that do things, you can add a date/time check at the top of the plugin and throw an exception if they are out of their license period.

You can also create new plugins that run on Retrieve of your entities that do the same thing. So if your user attempted to view a list of records for your entity while outside of their license period, they would also see an exception pop-up.

You can also put these checks into any Silverlight web-resources that you use, and even javascript web-resources. Don't depend on javascript obviously, but it could at least show the user friendly messages or reminders that they need to obtain a newer license.